# yii2 multi step form

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have just got accustomed to yii2

```
Am creating a multistep form in yii2 which involves three related tables
```

tables

```
User table:has         (idno(primary key), firstname, secondname and lastname)
Education table has:  (idno(foreign key), institution_name, year_completed, grade)
Contacts table has:   (idno(f.key),contact)
```

Models and relationships

Relation btwn user and contacts

```
 public function getContacs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contacts::className(), ['idno' => 'idno']);
}
 public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['idno' => 'idno']);
}
```

Relationship btwn user and education

```
public function getEducation()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Education::className(), ['idno' => 'idno']);
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['idno' => 'idno']);
}
```

How can I create a multistep form  that is in the first step  a user fills in the his details on the next step on education details the form automatically picks the userid and passes it to the education details until finishing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need  to maintain a flag for each step , for example for first_step = 0 , second_step = 0 third_step = 0 . if first step is filled out change the first_step = 1 do same for other , this fields should be present in user table or you can maintain another table using user id as foreign key . if first_step = 1 then when you login again and page will open where flag = 0 mean it will open the second step directly. This is a basic  concept so you can get idea , There are  other ways also .

Comment: How will I set up the controller.Do you have an existing example